# Access radeon setting on mac, 3d defective

Tags: display, imac

I am new at mac recently. The mid 2010 imac shows shattered lines and dots in any 3d apps. Chess is the example:

[image]
I tried the hardware test by hold 'd' but couldn't find problem. I tried format and install OS. This imac still has the problem.

I will try to downclock/underclock. How about adjust 3d setting so does mac have radeon's setting (catalyst)?

Comment: It's helpful if you post a screen shot of the problem, your OS version, etc.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.  Also, you might want to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS does not have Radeon Settings/Catalyst as Windows does. Apple publishes their own drivers through system updates. While Nvidia does offer their own Mac drivers, they often lag far behind the PC counterparts and don't seem to offer any sort of Wattman-equivalent for changing clock speeds.

While there is an app called [ATICellerator](http://thomas.perrier.name/index.html), it hasn't been updated in almost a decade, and almost certainly won't work with a more modern card, like the one in your iMac.

Conceivably, you could create a custom ROM and reflash your card using [Zeus](https://cindori.org/zeus-1-8/)–however, both Zeus and [the guides/support for such a modification are relatively limited](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/the-golden-guide-to-flashing-graphic-cards.877441/), especially for a niche card like yours–generally this was used to flash desktop PC cards with Mac firmwares. This is a potentially risky process that may leave you with bricked/dead hardware if you mess up–though you may decide you've got nothing left to lose.

The simplest and best solution is probably to just buy a replacement GPU and replace it [following a guide such as the one iFixit publishes.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Graphics+Card/9553) If your card is dying, underclocking it may not save it much longer anyways. If you want to test this, consider installing Windows and attempting to apply a clock change using some sort of reputable app such as Wattman (bundled with the AMD drivers) or [MSI Afterburner.](https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner) You may find that even then, clock changes refuse to stick (even within Windows) for one reason or another. Note that these changes will not pervade through to MacOS.